# How to write Spring Interceptor to handle any Web Service exception

Tags: web-services, cxf, interceptor

I am working on a Web Project which is having few SOAP Web Services that we are developing using CXF 2.7.8(& Spring 3.0.7). I have a requirement to add interceptor which can handle the exception occurred during a method call, extract the root cause and send it to the caller.

We don't have any Controllers in our web project as we don't have UI. The project is hosting few web services only.

I implemented a Spring based interceptor by referring to the sample code/example available on internet. By my interceptor is not being called when I call a webservice method. The same code/interceptor works fine in different web application which has a Controller (and uses Spring MVC flow).

I am not sure why it is not working? Is it because that we don't have Spring MVC based flow and I am trying to use a Spring Interceptor? If yes, then could somebody please suggest as how can I write an interceptor which will be called when some exception occurs. I am using CXF based SOAP web services.

Below is the Interceptor & Spring configuration that I tried:

public class ExceptionHandlerInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

```
private static final Logger LOG = Logger
        .getLogger(ExceptionHandlerInterceptor.class);

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    LOG.info("Before handling the request");
    return super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
}

@Override
public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
        ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
    LOG.info("After handling the request");
    super.postHandle(request, response, handler, modelAndView);
}

// @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
@Override
public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex)
        throws Exception {
    LOG.info("After rendering the view");
    System.out.println("Exception is-->" + ex);
    super.afterCompletion(request, response, handler, ex);
}
```

}

And this is the Spring configuration:

Comment: The XML configuration is: <mvc:interceptors>
<bean class="po.webservices.interceptor.ExceptionHandlerInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptors>

Comment: is there a need for spring interceptor? when there are lots of CXF interceptors. Why don't you use FaultInterceptors provided by cxf

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Karthik. I was also thinking to try CXF Interceptors. But then my lead suggested to use Spring AOP. I followed below links and got it working: http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-aop-examples-advice/
http://www.java4s.com/spring/spring-aop-throws-advice-example-with-complete-explanation/
http://www.javatechtipssharedbygaurav.com/2013/04/spring-aop-throws-advice.html